# how to perform same animation with different points on button click ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, ibaction

i am trying to increase the temperature with animation on button click
it is  working when i tap the button first time but when i tap the button again nothing happens.
I am using a image view (red color) for showing the temperature 
here is my code that i am using behind action 
[image: this is my meter[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbvQv.png)

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {

        self.progress.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation((self.progress.frame.origin.x -self.progress.frame.origin.x ), -30)
    })
```

it should increase each time i click the + button but its not happening
can anyone explain what is the issue ?

Comment: What do you expect this to result: self.progress.frame.origin.x -self.progress.frame.origin.x

Comment: i did this because my animation was moving in X axis also even i do not want it to  so i handled it in this way !

Comment: why don't you put 0 for x instead?

Comment: and this will move your image only the first time you should use CGAffineTransformConcat

Comment: can you guide me how to use CGAffineTransformConcat in this case ?

Comment: I'm going to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move your image you should do a concatenation of your transformations

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {

   let transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -30)
   self.progress.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.progress.transform, transform)
})
```

Comment: I don't know how it is better to use concat than just increment a variable. Variable probably is much simpler operation under the hood.

Comment: You're probably right but this way is easier to understand when you read it (only 2 lines and no instance variable to keep track of how many time a user tap on a button). And let' s be honest performance wise this won't make your app slow. So just the fact that is more readable and less complicated we can admit it's better than adding a variable

Comment: exactly in that case we need to track that how many time user tap the button

Answer (score 1):

CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation is not necessarily needed if only moving the frame. The same could be done simply by setting a new frame to the view.  Also, if you don't reset the transformation anywhere there is nothing to animate in the second time. Or instead of resetting, you should increment/decrement the value -30, not use the same value every time.

Comment: i do not want to reset it i want my bar"progress" (which is an imageview) to  move in Y axis from its last position whenever i click the button

Comment: and i saw a tutorial in which the tutor recommends to use CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation instead of moving view's frame directly

Comment: I have always done animations by just changing the frame with no problems. You are always setting the y translation to exactly -30. If you want incremental transformation then you need to add -30 to the previous translation.

Comment: Moving the frame is not a good idea especially if you use auto layout. CGAffineTransformation are recommended

Comment: You can also animate the auto layout constraints. If you don't have any constraints there shouldn't be any difference in performance.

Comment: thanks a lot. i created a var and check the number of times button is clicked and on 2nd click of button i gave the value -60 and it worked

Comment: That actually exactly pointed out the problem. There is nothing to animate if the same value is set every time. I can modify the answer to say the same thing without questions, if that's somehow better.